# How to add a custom HTTP query string field/value to ElasticSearch requests using NEST (.Net)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST, the .Net library for ElasticSearch.

I'd like to add my own query string to requests to ElasticSearch for tracking purpose.

For example,

`http://localhost:9200/index/type/123?SOMEFIELD=SOMEVALUE`

Give a ElasticClient object, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of NEST are you using? Do you want to send a unique query string key/value _per request_ or append the same value to each request?

Comment: Latest. Yes, I want to send unique query string key/value per request.